# Use Xcode to execute project created by Swift Package Manager

Tags: xcode, swift2, toolchain

I've created a project using the Swift Package manager. For that I ran "swift build --init" and then added two source files:

main.swift

```
import Foundation

print("Hello World")
let swifty = NSURLComponents(string: "https://swift.org")!
print("\(swifty.host!)")

let test = [1, 2, 3]

print(test)

 if Process.arguments.count != 2 {
     print("Usage: hello Name")
 } else {
     let name = Process.arguments[1]
     sayHello(name)
 }
```

and Greeter.swift

```
func sayHello(name: String) {
    print("Hello, \(name)!")
}
```

So it's very basic. When I run it using the executable directly (./.build/debug/LeagueScraper) it works like a charm.

However I would like to be able to run it directly from Xcode; for this I edit the scheme and set the Executable to my Product. The problem is that Xcode stores the .build in the Derived Data directory and then gives me this error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __TMPdSa
  Referenced from: /Users/aevitas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LeagueScraper-difkqqricvojhwdawinwisptcanb/Build/Products/Debug/LeagueScraper
  Expected in: /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-03-16-a.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx/libswiftCore.dylib
 in /Users/aevitas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LeagueScraper-difkqqricvojhwdawinwisptcanb/Build/Products/Debug/LeagueScraper
(lldb)
```

Sadly, I'm a bit of a noob here and I have no idea how to fix this.

I am using the latest development snapshot of Swift that is installed using the standard installer.

How can I tell Xcode to use a different toolchain for this one specific project?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the toolchain that Xcode is using to build the your code and the swift that `swift build` is part of.

This bug is fixed for the next snapshot. For now ensure you launch Xcode with the correct toolchain:

```
xcrun launch-with-toolchain /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest.xctoolchain
```

Comment: When is the next snapshot coming out? Thank you :-)